# Why am I getting JavaScript errors in my extended web application?

Tags: error, javascript, alternate-access-mapping

I have extended a web application in SharePoint Foundation 2010. Added an AAM from "http://servername" to "http://portal". Accessing the site with the AAM address (http://portal) will come up however I receive several script errors. Noticeably If I click on Page I get a persistant Loading message, then I am unable to click the navigation button or navigation button. Some examples of the errors on page from IE are "Syntax error ScriptResource.axd" "Syntax error WebResource.axd" "'Sys' is underfined Home.aspx" "'WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit' is undefined Home.aspx" "'Type' is undefined sp.core.js" "Object doesn't support this property or method cui.js" "Object expected core.js Code: 0 URI: http://portal/_layouts/1033/core.js?rev=1VDxRR0oL3%2FEtgWNP2%2BGbQ%3D%3D"

How ever if I access the site using "http://servername" everything works as expected. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem many times with customers and it's either been a misconfigured AAM or a problem with the load balancer config.  Can't provide any specific guidance on hthe load balancer without knowing what, if any, kind you are using.  But for AAM configuration, I've found this to be a useful link on more than one occassion:

http://www.sharepointpromag.com/article/sharepoint/configure-a-load-balancer-to-accept-only-ssl-requests

Comment: Thanks for the great article link. I followed through it and am still having the same result. It is possible that I missed a step, but I would like to clarify that I am not using a load balancer. My intention was to provide the internal users access to SharePoint with a "friendly" url ie. "http://portal" 
Thoughts?